# Jenkins build is failing with error "The IFilter for the file extension '.tif' is not installed" but working locally

Tags: c#, jenkins, continuous-integration, nunit, ocr

I have Jenkins server running on *Windows Server 2016* machine.
In my project, there are 25 unit test cases which are running successfully for OCR on local machine but these all are failing when building through Jenkins.
the error which I am getting is below:

```
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
NUnit VS Adapter 2.2.0.0 executing tests is started
Loading tests from  
D:\Storage.NET/Common/OCRSupport/OCRIFilterDetectionSupportLib/OCRIFilterDetectionSupportLib.Tests/bin/OC 
RIFilterDetectionSupportLib.Tests.dll
Run started: D:\Storage.NET/Common/OCRSupport/OCRIFilterDetectionSupportLib/OCRIFilterDetectionSupportLib.Tests/bin/OC 
RIFilterDetectionSupportLib.Tests.dll
X IFilterOCR_Extract_BottomLeft("testimage.tif") [426ms]
Error Message:
Labs.Storage.Exceptions.IFilterNotFoundException : The IFilter for the file extension '.tif' is not 
installed
Stack Trace:
at Labs.Storage.Components.TextExtractorClient.<DetectOCRText>d__11.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at OCRIFilterDetectionSupportLib.Tests.IFilterOCRTests.IFilterOCR_Extract_BottomLeft(String fileName) 
in 
D:\Store.NET\Common\OCRSupport\OCRIFilterDetectionSupportLib\OCRIFilterDetectionSupportLib.Tests\IFilter 
OCRTests.cs:line 149
```

these all are working locally but failing on Jenkins.

**My obserations are below:**

When I removed the *Windows TIFF IFilter* from my local machine then these are failing with the same error on local machine also but running well when installing *Windows TIFF IFilter.*
I have checked on Jenkins server machine and found that *Windows TIFF IFilter* is installed there still build are failing.

I have seen many solutions on stackoverflow but did not worked for me.

Is there anything which I am missing ?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is jenkins running as service and if yes, under which credential? A regular user or one of the built-in system ones?

Comment: @rene ,
Yes, all of our Jenkins jobs are running as service. Regular user credentials, they create a regular user specifically to run these jobs.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with how these IFilters work. You say you checked that they were installed. Did you check for the user that runs that job? If this is a per user config, checking with your account or that of an admin might not reveal the root causes.

Comment: @rene , 
Yes, I have checked for the user that runs that job and it is available there also.
Is there any way to find a solution for it ?

Comment: Maybe it is a 32/64 bits problem? Can you check if that process is running in 32 or 64 bits mode and compare with what you're running.

Comment: @rene , 
I have checked it, both are on same mode i.e, 64 bit